# OpenCV, cvRemap function has a weird unhandled exception

Tags: opencv, remap

I was learning OpenCV to calibrate and rectify a camera. The camera is already calibrated and now I am using cvRemap(src, dst, mapx, mapy) to un-distort the two images taken by the left and right cameras.

Each time the program runs to the line containing cvRemap(), it throws an unhandled exception called:

> Unhandled exception at 0x757dc41f in testagain.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x003fe73c..

And the console says:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.type() == dst.type() && dst.size() == mapx.size()) in unknown function, file ..\ ..\ ..\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp, line 3294

I did it according to *Learning OpenCV*. Note that the format of cvRemap is: `cvRemap(const CvMat* src, const CvMat* dst, const CvMat* mapx, const CvMat* mapy)`. Some guesses here:

1. Since the mapx and mapy are generated by another program and read in by myself, there contain some negative values and some values larger than the resolution of picture(640*480), I manually processed these values and set them back to the range of resolution. I hope this won't be a problem.
2. Before this trial, I calculated mapx and mapy through `cvInitUndistortRectifyMap()`, and when I called cvRemap, there is no exception. I don't know why.

Comment: Since mapx and mapy are generated by a different program, except for the values, do you make sure that `dst.size() == mapx.size()` as the error says?

Comment: @Bob Yeah, the mapx is 640*480 same as the dst's size.

Comment: and they are the same type? not mixing int and uchar or float and double?

Comment: @Hammer I checked it just now, they are both double.